# PostConstruct/Constructor for FacesComponent

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I've created FacesComponent which I want to initialize in constructor/postconstructor. The problem is that `getAttributes()` is empty in there. Below is the example.

```
@FacesComponent("articleComponent")
public class ArticleFacesComponent extends UINamingContainer {

    private Article article;

    public ArticleFacesComponent() {
        Object idObj = getAttributes().get("articleId"); // I want to get article id to initialize object but getAttributes() is empty
        ...
        article = em.find(Article.class, id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to perform the job in the `encodeAll()` method. It's invoked during render response, when the component is about to be rendered.

```
@Override
public void encodeAll(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    // Here.

    super.encodeAll(context);
}
```

Given that you're extending from `UINamingContainer`, you're most likely creating a backing component for a [composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info). In that case, this article should provide you useful insights to get started: [composite component with multiple input fields](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, accessing the DB in a component is a smell. Rather pass a fullworthy `Article` instance as component value instead of its ID. The component/renderer should only deal with front-end (HTTP/HTML) stuff based on the model, not with back-end (DB/SQL) stuff. You should provide the component *exactly* the model it needs to work with.

Comment: Thanks BalucS. I access DB in FacesComponent because I want to pass only articleId to CC (ex. `<cc:article galleryId="great-roger-gallery">`). Why? Because if I had to pass `Article` object I will need to create it somewhere. `FacesComponent` will check if article with that ID exists and if not it will be created. Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Like @BalusC said. But if you are using PrimeFaces you have to overwrite the `encodeBegin()` method. Else you may overwrite `encodeAll()`.